# WPF Databind control in write-only mode

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, listbox

I'm trying to fiddle a little with WPF bindings, so I created a simple project.
Here's the code:

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public int Age {
        get { return age; }
        set {
            age = value;
            FirePropertyChanged("Age");
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            FirePropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    private void FirePropertyChanged(string v)
    {
        if(PropertyChanged !=null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(v));
    }
    private int age;
    private string name;
}
```

My viewmodel contains ObservableCollection of Person, and single Person to track selected Person.

I've bound listbox's ItemsSource to ObservableCollection, and SelectedItem to single Person, called CurrentPerson. Also, I've bound TextBox to CurrentPerson.Name.

Code works fine, but whenever I change content of TextBox - my listbox also changes. And no matter what combination of "OneWay, TwoWay, OneWayToSource" binding modes on listbox\selecteditem I cannot prevent listbox from updating from CurrentPerson.

How can I prevent this behavior? I'd like to update listbox from CurrentPerson only by using ICommand interface from VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one copy of the `Person` object which is being used in both `ListBox.ItemsSource` and `TextBox.Text`, so naturally updating that object from one location will reflect the change in the other as well.

Two easy solutions would be

- Change the `BindingMode` on `TextBox.Text` to `Explicit`, so it doesn't update the Person object until you tell it to
- Use a separate string property for `TextBox.Text` and copy it over to your `SelectedPerson.Name` whenever the command executes

Personally I prefer the second option because I'm not a big fan of bindings that don't accurately reflect the data object behind the UI component, and it would allow the user to change the `SelectedItem` without resetting the TextBox value.

---

For an example of the second option, your ViewModel might look like this :

```
public class MyViewModel()
{
    ObservableCollection<Person> People { get; set; }
    Person SelectedPerson { get; set; }
    string NewPersonName { get; set; }
    ICommand UpdatePersonName { get; }
}
```

where the `UpdatePersonName` command would execute

```
SelectedPerson.Name = NewPersonName;
```

and the `CanExecute` would only return true if

```
SelectedPerson != null 
&& !NewPersonName.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() 
&& NewPersonName != SelectedPerson.Name
```

Comment: The second solution sounds awful to me. Why the hell would you want to pollute the ViewModel containing the List of Persons with edit-related properties? Pretty much violates the single responsibility principle of a ViewModel and is a code smell

Comment: @Tseng Hrm maybe I should clarify. I updated my answer. For me, the ViewModel should model the View, so if the View has a listbox of data, a textbox for a new name of the selected item, and a button, then the ViewModel should contain the data for all of that.

Comment: It's still a mixing of concerns. You end up mixing browsing, displaying and editing inside the same ViewModel. The above `MyViewModel` should be rather called `BrowserPeopleViewModel` (since that's what it actually does) and depending if you are in view or editing mode display `PersonViewModel` or "EditPersonViewModel` next to the listbox.After all, the model may be a complex one and separated by mutiple edit views (change shipping address, payment information, marriage status). Putting it all into one ViewModel will cause you to replicate dozens of properties and create hard to maintain code

Comment: There's more than one way of building a WPF application. What you are describing is one way, and what I am describing is another. It all depends on how you want to build your application :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I've followed the question properly.
So, we have a class Person as

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public int Age
        {
            get { return age; }
            set
            {
                age = value;
                FirePropertyChanged("Age");
            }
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                name = value;
                FirePropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }

        private void FirePropertyChanged(string v)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(v));
        }
        private int age;
        private string name;
    }
```

And we have a view model as

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Person> List { get; set; }
        Person currentPerson;
        public Person CurrentPerson {
            get { return currentPerson; }
            set { currentPerson = value;
            FirePropertyChanged("CurrentPerson");
            }
        }

        private void FirePropertyChanged(string v)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(v));
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    }
```

The xaml is

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding List}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentPerson}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" Width="100" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>       
</ListBox>
```

And I bind the view model to the view via

```
    ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();
    vm.List = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(1,10))
    {
        vm.List.Add(new Person() { Name = "Test" + i.ToString(), Age= i });
    }
    vm.CurrentPerson = null;
    this.DataContext = vm;
```

Whenever I change the value at textbox, it updates the name properly. I tried to add a handler for list changed, but it doesn't happen to get triggered.

```
vm.List.CollectionChanged += List_CollectionChanged;
void List_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Action.ToString());
        }
```

Can you comment if it isn't the same as your problem statement?

Comment: I think the OPs problem is they have a separate `<TextBox Text="{Binding CurrentPerson.Name}" />` next to the ListBox, and they want to be able to update that TextBox.Text without the ListBox data updating.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control when and what is saved/updated, you obviously need is a ViewModel for editing your Person model.

When selecting a person in your Listbox, you have to pass the person's id (avoid passing the object itself) to the `PersonEditViewModel` which is bound to the properties that shall be edited, load the persons data into the `PersonEditViewModel` and then edit. Once you hit the "Save" button, it should commit the change and update the database or whatever you are using for persistence.

Use either events/messages to pass values/events back and forth, or use a navigation approach (like `INavigationAware` interface in Prism).